# Control unresponsiveness/Delay in two player game

Tags: pygame

I'm new to pygame (and game development in general) but have been building a simple two player game where two rectangles can move around the screen on some platforms. I mapped player 1 to the asdw and player two to the arrow keys. Recently I've run into a problem where the controls seem to be delayed/unresponsiveness. I'm not exactly sure what is causing the error, so its difficult to bug test, Here are some things I've noticed:

- Only occurs when both players are moving
- unresponsiveness only seems to occur when a jump is called. Otherwise the two players can move in the x direction just fine
- Player two seems to be delayed more than player one

My only hunch right now is that inefficient code is causing the delay, but I'm not quite sure. There doesn't appear to be any slowdown. It rather feels like the controls are interfering with each other.

I'll post my code if anyone wants to take a look. I'm fully aware that I didn't follow many coding standards as this is something I started without much knowledge, and have continually built on it. I also chose not to use the sprite class to try and get a better understanding of this stuff myself.

Thanks!

https://github.com/ChristianD37/basicGameStart (Main game code is in Movement_Test.py)

Comment: at first look code seems OK. I don't see where it could be problem. But `Sprite` and `pygame.Rect()` (and its method to check collision) uses code in C/C++ (library SDL) so it can be faster. I wouldn't use also `getX()` if I can get directly `self.x` - executing function needs some time. I would use also directly `user.downkey = keys[pygame.K_s]` and `two.jumpkey_pressed(keys[pygame.K_KP_ENTER])` without `if/else` because `keys[pygame.K_s]` and `keys[pygame.K_KP_ENTER]` gives `True` or `False`

Comment: eventually you could use `start = time.time()` in one place and `end = time.time()` to measure `end - start` - or you would have to learn how ot use [Profiler](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/profiler.html) in some IDE.

Comment: BTW: you could also ask on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for other suggestions

Comment: Please read the [Code Review FAQ on asking questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436/52915) *before* posting there.

Comment: Considering the app is turned unresponsive and this is not intended behaviour, I'd say it's not ready for review yet. Sluggish, ok. Unresponsive though smells like it doesn't work yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cduen, it is probably your keyboard... certain keyboards (and usually wireless ones) only allow a certain amount of keys to be pressed at one time before the other become unresponsive - this is due to the way they are built with multiple keys on one circut

Because of this hardware limitation, one has to look for keyboards with 6KRO, 10KRO or NKRO... with the 6,10 or N indicating how many keys can be pressed without “ghosting”. Most standard keyboards are set up with multiple keys in one circuit for cost savings so that is why you can only press so many keys before it can’t take any more input.

I ran into similar problem with a two player game I created and the new NKRO keyboard solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your input! My keyboard is a pretty cheap dell one, so I can see this being a problem. Is there any way i can test this before I go out and buy a new keyboard?

Comment: CDuen... I just did some google research and picked up the following from Walmart online for around $100 but sure you could get almost anywhere and / or similar products: 104 Keys NKRO USB Wired Blue Switch Keyboard ABS Keycaps RGB Backlight Ergonom

Comment: CDuen... if the change in keyboard worked and you liked my answer, please click on the checkmark beside it to green please as that is how the stackoverflow community works.